# Pass run time parm from Procedure to View (in MySQL)?

Tags: mysql

MySQL: I have a View in the DB. Now I would like to Call a Stored Procedure w/a parameter and have the parameter available to the View. Is this possible and if so, how?

TIA

Comment: Pretend the View is a Table; show us how you would write a simple SP using that Table.  (This may lead to a different "Answer".)

Comment: @Rick,

I want to Call SP GetRosters with a parameter that is used in the View to select MemberNumber. This is all new to me so I am using Trial & error.

DELIMITER  $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRosters()
BEGIN

CREATE VIEW Vroster AS 

SELECT r.MemberNumber, 
 member.First, 
 member.Last, 
 member.Email, 
 member.PhoneNumber,
FROM roster AS r
 JOIN member on r.MemberNumber = member.MemberNumber 

END $$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: `GetRosters()` is declared to have no 'parameters'.  Perhaps you are using "parameter" to mean something else??

Comment: @Rick, I was using the ( ) as a place holder until I find out how to pass it along to the View. Sorry about the messy coding. I did not know how to make it a coding block so it would be easier to read. Again, this is my first time post.

Answer (score 1):

View cannot be parametrized. But you may use some service table as view's datasource, and set needed values/criteria in it.

### DEMO.

```
CREATE TABLE datatable (id INT, val INT);
INSERT INTO datatable VALUES (11,111), (22,222), (33,333);
```

```
CREATE TABLE criteria (id1 INT, id2 INT);

CREATE VIEW getdata AS
SELECT datatable.*
FROM datatable
JOIN criteria ON datatable.id BETWEEN criteria.id1 AND criteria.id2;

CREATE PROCEDURE calldata ()
SELECT * FROM getdata;
```

```
INSERT INTO criteria VALUES (5, 15);
CALL calldata;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 111 |

```
TRUNCATE criteria;
INSERT INTO criteria VALUES (20, 100);
CALL calldata;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 222 |
| 33 | 333 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lg9K5DQK)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRosters(INT _foo IN)
...
BEGIN
    ...
    SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE x = _foo;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

(I use the *convention* of a leading `_` on arguments and local variables to distinguish them from column names.)